# Why is OIDC-provider stuck in Deleting state in Cloudformation in AWS?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have a stack where a change to the Cloudformation template caused the OIDC-provider that was created in the stack to be deleted.

When updating the stack, it seems that the stack never leaves the
`UPDATE_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS` state. I believe this is because of the OIDC-provider never finishes to delete. I can only see the `DELETE_IN_PROGRESS` status event for that resource, never the `DELETE_COMPLETE` event. When looking for identity providers in IAM, the identity provider is removed though, but Cloudformation doesn't seem to catch on.

This has been the case for about two hours. Can I solve this in any way without tearing down the stack?